# Getting random records and display in particular format using PHP and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, random

I have a DB with 100 questions and multiple answers for it. I wanted to display in a quiz format selecting 20 random questions at a time. I have done something like this below

```
$m=new MongoClient(); 
  $db=$m->mydb; 
  $c=$db->quiz; 
 $cursor = $c->find()
      $n = 20;
            foreach ($cursor as $obj) { 
             $links=array('$obj["question"]<br><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="$obj["ch1"]"> $obj["ch1"]<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="$obj["ch2"]"> $obj["ch2"]<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                                  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="$obj[ch3"]"> $obj["ch3"]</p>');

    $rand_keys = array_rand($links, $n);
    echo "<center>". "<br><table><tr><td>";

    echo "1.&nbsp;&nbsp;". $links[$rand_keys[0]] . "<br>";
    echo "</td></tr><tr><td>";
    echo "2.&nbsp;&nbsp;".$links[$rand_keys[1]] . "<br>";
    echo "</td></tr><tr><td>";
    echo "3.&nbsp;&nbsp;". $links[$rand_keys[2]] . "<br>";
    echo "</td></tr><tr><td>";


    }
```

It is not working. Is there anything wrong with th code? Please help me either finding the wrong to make it work or any method that would achieve my purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iteration using mongoDB and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314980/iteration-using-mongodb-and-php)

Comment: @AlexBlex I'm not sure it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Puneeth, which version of MongoDB do you use?

Comment: @ConstantinGuay, 2.6.11.

Comment: @Alex, Its not duplicate, Iteration was to know how to access nested loops in PHP and MongoDB. Now how to display in particular format , where the code is not working here.

Comment: @Puneeth ok so you can't use MongoDB 3.2's new feature [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/). On way to get random values from the database, without PHP, could be to add random entries. You add a field `'random' => rand(1,10000)` (depending on how many docs you'll have) and then, in your query, you ask for a random value too.

Comment: @ConstantinGuay, As I am naive in PHP and MongoDB I may struggle to understand. I need to display in quiz format taking the questions and multiple answers from DB. I mean for this I need PHP code, so whats your point?

Comment: @Puneeth yes, you need PHP to format the code, but not to get random values. That's why I do not add this as an answer, it's only a partial answer to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK, considering other *non-duplicated* questions, I would recommend to learn basics of php alone and try to iterate a hardcoded nested array to print expected output.

So some problems with the code in the question:

- it does not fetch random questions
- it prints nothing but adds 1 long string to `links` array. Please learn  [difference between `'` and `"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)
- there is no loop to iterate answers, and it is not valid php code at all

The working code (again considering document structure from [*non-duplicated question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314980/iteration-using-mongodb-and-php)) may look like:

```
foreach ($cursor as $obj) { 
    echo $obj["question"];
    foreach($obj["answers"] as $key=>$answer) {
        echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $key . '" value="'.$answer.'">';
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code which prints randomly. Now can you give me some useful answers? Please remember this work without the for loop. What can be done to make it work.

Comment: No Puneeth. Evidently I cannot. I give up.

Comment: If so then why isn't this working.  echo  '<input type="radio" name="'q1'" value="'$obj["ch1"]'">';  Please remember no nested records, so accessing obj[ch1].